# Unrecognized option: -Xincgc (Minecraft client)

Tags: java, minecraft

so I am making a minecraft client and when it comes to running it in both debug and running it normally through eclipse I keep getting the error "Unrecognized option: -Xincgc".
These windows also pop up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYDXP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kju58.png)

I have already tried reinstalling both eclipse and jdk, but to no success.

I'm thinking it is because there is no eclipse.ini:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNHDZ.png)

I wonder if this is something to do with it?

Comment: I have fixed it i just had to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I just have to delete the argument.